# If an input string too id long or has a paragraphs won't copy it all

Tags: python, input, paragraph

I have a question about `input`

```
description = input('add description: ')
```

I'm adding a text using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

For example:

> "The short story is a crafted form in its own right. Short stories
> make use of plot, resonance, and other dynamic components as in a
> novel, but typically to a lesser degree. While the short story is
> largely distinct from the novel or novella/short novel, authors
> generally draw from a common pool of literary techniques.
>
> Determining what exactly separates a short story from longer fictional
> formats is problematic. A  classic definition of a short story is that
> one should be able to read it in one sitting, a point most notably
> made in Edgar Allan Poe's essay "The Philosophy of Composition"
> (1846)"

Result is:

```
description = "The short story is a crafted form in its own right. Short stories make use of plot, resonance, and other dynamic components as in a novel, but typically to a lesser degree. While the short story is largely distinct from the novel or novella/short novel, authors generally draw from a common pool of literary techniques."
```

Whilst I want description to hold the entire text chain I copied.

Comment: Yes; you're missing reading the documentation of `input`.  By definition, the input string is terminated by the EOL character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the `input()` function terminates on an End Of Line or `\n`. I would suggest using a setup like this:

```
line = []
while True:
    line = input()
    if line == "EOF":
        break
    else:
        lines.append(line)
text = ' '.join(lines)
```

What this does is read input and add it to a array until you type in "EOF" on its own line and hit enter. Thsis should solve the multi line problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing here is that an input ends as soon as enter is hit or (in this case) the next line is started. The only way to use enter (I'm just going to call It that, hope you know what I mean) is to instead of actually writing a new paragraph just to write \n, since that is the representation of enter in a string. If you want to go around this issue though I highly recommend you learn how to use the TKinter model, since if you want to create any kind of app for frontend It is one of the best modules. Here a link to get you started https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm

Comment: I'll probably jump to GUI once I'll learn more about python, I literally know nothing atm, I'll need to read the INPUT and PRINT documentation